# python : converting text file to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file names xrb.txt, the first few lines of which looks like this -

```
1   N.A.    9.10    9.66 
2   N.A.    8.20    8.48 
3   N.A.    8.70    8.11  
4   6.34    4.60    4.39 
5   6.07    <5.74   4.35 
6   N.A.    5.10    4.42 
7   2.92    3.20    2.05 
8   <1.25   1.44    0.72
```

I need to make a dictionary with the first column (i.e. 1, 2, 3 …) as the keys and others in the respective rows as the values for each key.

Is there a easy way to do it in python??

I was trying the following, but it is not working proper and i am sure i am complicating it a bit too much:

```
xrbdic = {}

f = open("xrb.txt")
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    pa = [p.strip() for p in line.split()]
    xrbdic[parts[0]] = (pa[1], pa[2], pa[3])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason your code doesn't work is a silly typo:

```
xrbdic[parts[0]] = (pa[1], pa[2], pa[3])
```

This will raise a `NameError` on `parts`, because there's no such variable. Change it to `pa`, and you get exactly the dictionary you were asking for.

---

Meanwhile, you're not overcomplicating things that badly. But can you simplify things a bit? Sure.

First, `line.split()` already strips off all the whitespace between the split parts, so you don't need to strip them individually.

And that includes the trailing newline, so you don't need the line-wide strip either.

Second, you can use a slice instead of explicitly listing all of the parts.

While we're at it, you never `close` the file, which is a bad idea for anything but a quick&dirty script that's going to exit immediately. You can use a `with` statement to make that simpler.

So:

```
xrbdic = {}
with open("xrb.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        pa = line.split()
        xrbdic[pa[0]] = pa[1:]
```

And then it's pretty easy to turn the whole thing into a dict comprehension:

```
with open('xrb.txt') as f:
    xrbdic = {pa[0]: pa[1:] for pa in map(str.split, f)}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed help.. even without the typing mistake, my method was messy compared to the one u suggested.. thank you :)
(1.25am is no time to work, i should probably sleep - it was a really stupid typo)

Comment: @Panchi: I make the same kinds of stupid typos in the middle of the afternoon. It's always easier to spot them in other people's code than your own.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the last line in your code to the following.

`xrbdic[pa[0]] = (pa[1], pa[2], pa[3])`

You wrote parts, when in fact you should have written pa.

Comment: :( i can not believe i can make such stupid mistake.. thank u for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary comprehension may be a more idiomatic answer.

```
with open('xrb.txt','r') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

###please ignore
#xrbdic = {p.split()[0]:(p.split()[1],p.split()[2],p.split()[3]) for p in raw_text}
##old ugly one-liner

rows = [line.split() for line in lines]
xrbdic = {row[0]:(row[1],row[2],row[3]) for row in rows}
```

Comment: A dictionary comprehension that calls `split` on the string over and over and over and over is definitely not idiomatic. Violating DRY like this makes the code harder to read and slower to run, and much more prone to stupid mistakes that are hard to notice and debug.

Comment: Also, why would you read the whole file into one big string just to call `splitlines` on it, when you could have used the file itself as an iterable of lines, as the OP was already doing? That's also making the code slower and less readable for no good reason.

Comment: I could have used `text=f.readlines()` instead, but since I'm doing the exact same execution later it seemed superfluous. I chose to use `f.read()` and allow the file to close because I didn't need it open anymore -- I'm of the inclination that keeping the file open while I do operation on its data is harmful once I've read it. As for splitting the string -- is there a happier way to do that in the list comp? I tried to do `{p[0]: (p[1],p[2],p[3]) for line in raw_text.splitlines() for p in line.split()}` but that syntax is wrong for reasons that are apparent to me now.

Comment: In any case, a dictionary comprehension IS the right way to read a string into a dictionary, whether I do so by `f.readlines()` or `f.read()` and `f.splitlines()`.

Comment: Using `readlines` would be even sillier. `f` is already an iterable of lines. You don't need to do anything to get an iterable of lines out of it, just use it. Also, in order to close the file a few microseconds early, you triple the memory usage (you need to whole the giant string, the list of strings, and the dict), prevent Python from interleaving (fast) work with (slow) I/O, and increase the amount of work that needs to be done. That's a really bad optimization.

Comment: As for only splitting the string once… I already showed a way to do that 10 minutes before you posted this answer, but if it isn't obvious: just iterate over a genexpr or `map` that itself iterates over the file, instead of iterating over the file directly.

Comment: … or I suppose you could use a listcomp instead of a genexpr if you have a burning need to use up even more memory or reduce the number of cache hits…

Comment: I revised a little, but your dict comprehension is much better -- your edit hadn't appeared by the time I'd answered. I didn't know you could iterate over a file object -- I've always read it into a variable and iterated over that. Using `map` to split each line is an awesome trick.

Comment: Next answer I'll be sure to write a recursive function that reads the whole file but only operates on one line each recursion, finally returning a listcomp and use `list.extend` to concat into an output. No need to be cheap -- modern computers have too much memory anyway! ;)